# Angular Currency Formatter with Comma

Tags: angularjs

I am using following syntax to format euro amount in angular

```
{{ 20,00 | currency : "€" : 2}}
```

what produces

> "20.00€"

Is there any simple way to format (using this syntax) the Euro price with comma instead of dot. so like

> "20,00€"

?

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/currency

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For localisation angular leverages i18n for localization and gloablization of applications. Using the euro symbol will not give you the formatting of comma vs. period.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/i18n

You'll need to include the formatting by including the correct i18n script in your project.  Here's the example from angular if your application needs german formatting.

```
<html ng-app>
 <head>
….
   <script src="angular.js"></script>
   <script src="i18n/angular-locale_de-de.js"></script>
….
 </head>
</html>
```

If you need to format your currency based upon the symbol for the currency though, you'll need to implement a custom filter.

Answer (score 3):

You can overwrite locale options with `$provide.decorator`:

```
app.config(['$provide', function ($provide) {
    $provide.decorator('$locale', ['$delegate', function ($delegate) {
        $delegate.NUMBER_FORMATS.DECIMAL_SEP = ',';
        return $delegate;
    }]);
}]);
```