# AngularJS dot to comma

Tags: angularjs

I'm new angularjs student, and my program receive a .json file with prices, but they are all with dots, i want to create a directive or something to substitute dots to comma's.

Can anyone help me please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you probably want to do is format your prices through the `currency` filter, which will work with a comma if you install the correct localization files. You can see an example of german localization at [Angular Currency Formatter with Comma](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31563678/angular-currency-formatter-with-comma)

Comment: I like this solution better than using `replace`, because you don't change the data. Upvoting this one.

Comment: @trichetriche i agree.

Answer (score 0):

Why cant you just use simple javascript replace? You should be able to extract the variable you want, then do something like this.

```
variable = variable.replace(".",",");
```

[click here](http://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/jsref_replace.asp)

**you should be able to integrate this code into your angular application seamlessly**